# Is it safe to run explain <insert query in hive> on production database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, sql-execution-plan, query-tuning

We have many hive queries that take lot of time on production
most of them are insert queries.
want to check the execution plan and table related data so we are thinking of checking the plan of this query

is it safe to run "explain insert into table... .." on production

just want to be sure on what i am doing as I am new to hive, but in production support and L3 team.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining a query doesn't actually execute the results, so you should be fine... If you are on a team, have someone more experienced review your actions